# Output clause with left join, how to?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to do something along those lines:

```
DELETE TOP(1) m
FROM MyTable m
OUTPUT deleted.*
LEFT JOIN MyOtherTable ON MyOtherTable.SomeColumn=s.SomeColumn
```

I know this works:

```
DELETE TOP(1) 
FROM MyTable
OUTPUT deleted.*
```

And this also works (although pointless):

```
DELETE TOP(1) m 
FROM MyTable m
LEFT JOIN MyOtherTable ON m.SomeColumn=MyOtherTable.SomeColumn
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Move the `OUTPUT` clause to before the `JOIN`

```
DELETE TOP(1) m 
OUTPUT deleted.* 
FROM MyTable m 
LEFT JOIN MyOtherTable ON MyOtherTable.SomeColumn=s.SomeColumn
```

Comment: No problem - glad to be of help.